# What are non-monotonous computable convergent sequences of rationals with non-computable rate of convergence?

Tags: calculus, logic, computability

A computable convergent sequence of rationals can have a non-computable rate of convergence.  By a rate of convergence of a sequence $(q_k)_k$, I mean a function $f : \omega \rightarrow \omega$ such that for all $x\in\omega$ we have $m \ge f(x) \Rightarrow |q_m - q_{f(x)}|<2^{-x}$.  This $f$ is $\Delta_2$ if $(q_k)_k$ is computable.

For example, if $q_k = 0.(K[k]) := \sum_{x \in K[k]}2^{-x}$, where $K[k]$ is $k$-th approximation of the halting problem, the minimum rate of convergence is a modulus of $K$ and Turing equivalent to $K$.

While I have some intuitive idea about monotonous sequences as above, I have difficulty understanding rate of convergence for non-monotonous sequences.  In particular: can I control the rate of convergence of a computable non-monotonous sequence to be an arbitrary $\Delta_2$ function?

Comment: What if you take your monotone sequence $q_k$, and replace every other term $q_{2k}$ with $2q_{2k-1}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean $2q_{2k}-1$, right?  I came up with something similar, but I wanted something not ad-hoc.

Comment: I think I meant what I wrote --- replace the 2nd term with twice the 1st term, the 4th term with twice the 3rd term, the 6th term with twice the 5th term, and so on. The sequence should still be computable and rational, but not monotone. But what I missed was that unless the original sequences converges to zero, the modified sequence won't converge. So maybe better to replace $q_{2k}$ with $2^{-k}+q_{2k-1}$.